# Override default protocol client for Electron App in Linux

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to set my Electron app as a default protocol client for 'magnet:' in Ubuntu Linux. But the default protocol handler, for now, is `Transmission`.

```
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('magnet', process.execPath, [])
```

It always returns **false** when I run the app as the regular user or even as root. And 'magnet:' links are handled by Transmission :(

What am I doing wrong?

PS.:

```
Electron v2.0.6; 
Chromium v61.0.3163.100; 
Node v8.9.3; 
v8 v6.1.534.41
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to test this functionality only with the built version of your code and not in your development environment!

Here is a really quick example on how to use the protocol handler for 'tel'.
https://github.com/DEDaniel/electron-tel-protocol-handler